# Script Powershell for MFA call

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble running this script. I am supposed to call using Strong authentication requirements which means users that enabled MFA using the MFA portal will be displayed if I am not mistaken.

```
Connect-MsolService
$role = getMsolRole -rolename "Company Administrator"
$rm = get-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId $role.ObjectId

foreach ($c in $rm)

{


Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $c.EmailAddress | Select DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, @{N="MFA Status"; E={ if($_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.Count -ne 0) { $_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State.toString() } else 'Disabled' }}
```

Error is

```
At line:9 char:225
+ ... { $_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State.toString() } else 'Disabl ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing statement block after 'else' keyword.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingStatementBlockAfterElse
```

Edited:

If even you can clarify the difference between calling MFA using StrongAuthenticationMethods and using StrongAuthenticationRequirements that will be good. So I can reproduce this code.

Problem with our MFA audit code is that it displays that system administrators are having MFA disabled even though they are claiming they are already enabled.

This is the audit code which returns admins with wildcard administrator are disabled.

```
Function Get-O365AdminMFAStatus{
    $AdminData=@()
    $objRole=@()
    $Domain = $(get-addomain).dnsroot
    $Log = "C:\temp\Audit\$Domain O365 Admin MFA Status $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"

    try{
        $Roles = Get-MsolRole | where {$_.name -LIKE "*Administrator*"}
        $Roles = ($Roles).name

        foreach ($Role in $Roles){
            $Members = Get-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId (Get-MsolRole -RoleName $Role).ObjectId 
            foreach ($Member in $Members){
                $MsUser = $Member | Get-MsolUser
                if($MsUser.StrongAuthenticationMethods.Count -eq 0) {
                    $Enabled = "False"
                    write-host $Role - $Member.DisplayName "No MFA enabled" -foregroundcolor red
                }
                Else{
                    $Enabled = "True"
                    write-host $Role - $Member.DisplayName "MFA enabled" -foregroundcolor green
                }   

                Try{
                    $Exist = [bool](Get-mailbox $MsUser.UserPrincipalName -erroraction SilentlyContinue)
                    if ($Exist){
                        $MBStats = Get-MailboxStatistics $MsUser.UserPrincipalName
                        $LastLogon = $MBstats.LastLogonTime
                    }
                    Else{
                        $LastLogon = "N/A"
                    }
                }
                Catch{
                    $LastLogon = "N/A"
                }

                $objRole = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                $objRole | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Role Name" -Value $Role
                $objRole | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Display Name" -Value $Member.DisplayName
                $objRole | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UPN" -Value $Member.UserPrincipalName
                $objRole | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Licensed" -Value $Member.IsLicensed
                $objRole | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Last Logon" -Value $LastLogon
                $objRole | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MFA Enabled?" -Value $Enabled

                $AdminData += $objRole
            }
        }

        $AdminData | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $Log 
        write-host ""
        write-host "CSV Export Complete to $Log" -foregroundcolor yellow
    }
    Catch{
        Write-host "There was an error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

Get-O365AdminMFAStatus
```

anyways if you have clarifications with the question I will edit.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: Error is you missed a `{` between `else` and `'Disabled'` > `else { 'Disabled' }`

Answer (score 0):

From the error you receive it's quite obvious, what you should correct:

> Missing statement block after 'else' keyword

You're missing curly braces after `else` so it should be:

```
else {'Disabled'}
```

I checked your cmdlet against my accounts (I have 2FA enabled) and `StrongAuthenticationRequirements` is empty object for me (checked on many accounts - attempt to clarify below). I think that you should use `StrongAuthenticationMethods` property instead. It contains information about channels that were configured for 2FA.

Finally, your code would look like this:

```bsh
foreach ($c in $rm) {
  Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $c.EmailAddress | Select DisplayName, UserPrincipalName,
  @{N="MFA Status"; E={ if($_.StrongAuthenticationMethods.Count -ne 0) { "$($_.StrongAuthenticationMethods.Count) methods found" } else {'Disabled'} }}
}
```

But you might notice some entries erroring with such info:

> Get-MsolUser : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'UserPrincipalName' because it is null.

To get rid of that, important thing is to filter out `ServicePrincipal` members from `Get-MsolRoleMember` (for example, I have RMS and PowerBI Information Service, you might have none or different ones):

```bsh
foreach ($c in $rm | Where-Object {$_.rolemembertype -eq 'user'}) {
  Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $c.EmailAddress | Select DisplayName, UserPrincipalName,
  @{N="MFA Status"; E={ if($_.StrongAuthenticationMethods.Count -ne 0) { "$($_.StrongAuthenticationMethods.Count) methods found" } else {'Disabled'} }}
}
```

---

#### Clarification about `StrongAuthenticationMethods` and `StrongAuthenticationRequirements`

From what I read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userstates) it seems like `StrongAuthenticationRequirements` applies for per-user MFA. If your tenant is using Conditional Access based MFA, that property might be empty (checked on my tenant). So I guess `StrongAuthenticationMethods` is more reliable.

---

**NOTE**: I also tested the part of long code you have posted and it works correctly for me. And you have a typo in `getMsolRole` - should be `Get-MsolRole`

Comment: thank you for the reply. so the long audit script worked for you returned admins* with MFA enabled. mine still says no MFA even though the admins are saying they have it. that is what is puzzling me. So I had to distinguish StrongAuthentication Methods from Requirements.

Comment: What you can do is to check what are values of these properties for you, when you check Get-MsolUser for them.